# Xcode 11 Beta 5 updates have broken my project indiscriminately

Tags: swiftui, xcode11

After downloading Xcode 11 beta 5 i am seeing a lot of what appear to be 'random errors' (Please see code example below for more clarification) that i can not seem to resolve. I have read through the documentation and it's still a complete mystery to me.

```
  struct RegistrationForm : View {

    @Binding var emailAddress : String
    @Binding var password : String



    var body: some View{

            VStack(alignment: .leading){ ///The error appears here **


                Text(verbatim: "Email address")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(.leading, 12)
                TextField($emailAddress)
                    .padding(.all)



                Text(verbatim: "Password")
                    .foregroundColor(Color.black)
                    .bold()
                    .font(.subheadline)
                    .padding(.leading, 12)
                SecureField($password)
                    .padding(.all)

            }

    }

}

///////Error message ///////
**
Static member 'leading' cannot be used on instance of type 'HorizontalAlignment'
```

As you can see from the code, i am applying .leading to a VStack, not a HStack.... Any ideas? As this error message is clearly incorrect.

Comment: Please note, after looking through my project, it appears all the errors i am seeing appear under a view with @Binding variables.. could have something to do with it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a no longer available initializer for `TextField` and `SecureField`:

Change your textfield to:

```swift
TextField("", text: $emailAddress)
```

And your secure textfield to:

```swift
SecureField("", text: $password)
```

*Note: The first parameter is the placeholder*

Comment: life saver! I knew it would be something simple i was missing. Much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. When dealing with messages that make no sense, start commenting out code, until the error is more meaningful. In your case, I started by commenting all the modifiers in all the views. The error then became obvious. Good luck!